# Resource Controller Concept

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7

I am unable to find the issue. It is showing 404|Not Found

update.blade.php

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
<h1>Update Post</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.update', $post) }}"  >
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="body"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

PostController.php (a resource controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\posts;
use Sessions; 

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $post = posts::all();

        return view('post.index', compact('post');      
    }
    public function create(Request $req)
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new posts;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function show($data)
    {
        $post = posts::findOrFail($data);
        return view('posts.read', compact('post','$post'));
    }

    public function edit(posts $post)
    {
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }

 
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
        $post = posts::find($id);
        $post->title =  $request->get('title');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }

   
}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

please tell me what is the issue in this.
one of the advice I got is to change the name of view file i.e update.blade.php to edit.blade.php. I don't know how does it help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: Do you have a view file `edit.blade.php`? Because the `update` method doesn't have/need a view. "_It is showing 404|Not Found_" When/where does it show that? When submitting the form? Or on your `edit` route?

Comment: change the name of view file name update.blade.php to edit.blade.php or change `return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));` to `return view('posts.update', compact('post'));` and add `$post = posts::find($id);` to `edit function`

Comment: @xNoJustice
I tried it already and did try again. Still Not Working :(
did  return view('posts.update', compact('post')); and added $post = posts::find($id); to edit function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should change `edit.blade.php` instead of `update.blade.php`

Second you should not call model like this `use App/posts;` It is wrong. It must be `use App\Post;` in your `PostController`

Third you should change `edit()` in your controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }
```

You should use `$post->id` instead of `$post`in your form action

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
<h1>Update Post</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.update', $post->id) }}"  >
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="body"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

**Then check**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($id);//check id before update

        $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
        $post = posts::find($id);
        $post->title =  $request->get('title');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning the view: `view('post.edit')`.
But you say that the file is called `update.blade.php`.

So you will have to rename the file to `edit.blade.php` **or** you need to change your edit function as follows, so that it returns the update blade file:

```
public function edit(posts $post)
    {
        return view('posts.update', compact('post'));
    }
```